# How do I get passed Elasticsearch Updating or Inserting using Python TypeError?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have a weird issue.  If I use curl with the payload I am sending to Elasticsearch I have no issues.  When I try to pass JSON to elastic via a web service using Python I get, depending on how I set the payload

- TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
- elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, 'action_request_validation_exception', **'Validation Failed: 1: script or doc is missing;')**

To help debug this I took the code out and ran it inline to try to figure it out.

To create the record I run the following.

```
edit_author1 = {"name": "Sheldon Sid", "myid": 18}
resp = es.index(index="radsearch", doc_type="default", id=18, body={"doc": edit_author1})
```

This works for the initial creation of the record when using es.create or es.index and it returns the following just as it does if I use curl from the terminal.

```
{
  "_index": "radsearch",
  "_type": "default",
  "_id": "18",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "doc": {
      "name": "Sheldon Sid",
      "myid": 18
    }
  }
}
```

It works as expected. When I try to run an update where I have the following

```
resp = es.update(index="radsearch", doc_type="default", id=18, body={'doc': edit_author1})
```

The above returns

```
{
  "_index": "radsearch",
  "_type": "default",
  "_id": "18",
  "_version": 2,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "doc": {
      "name": "Sheldon Sid",
      "myid": 18
    **},
    "myid": 18,
    "name": "Sheldon Sid"
  }**
}
```

But the document repeats itself as a separate entry under doc. If I run it via curl it updates the document and does not create a second entry as above.

If I try to run create or update without the doc key I get a **TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'**

```
resp = es.update(index="radsearch", doc_type="default", id=18, body={edit_author1})
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

If I try to run update as

```
resp = es.update(index="radsearch", doc_type="default", id=18, body=edit_author1)
```

I get

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: 
TransportError(400, 'action_request_validation_exception', 
                    'Validation Failed: 1: script or doc is missing;')
```

Any ideas on how to fix this as I am stuck?

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 4):

Finally found the answer. It is a formatting issue.  I was close.  In order to use the Elasticsearch API you need to append doc for you are going to run an update.

For the initial insert this works

```
edit_author1 = {"name": "Sheldon Sid", "myid": 18}
```

When you want to update you will need to modify it like this

```
edit_author1 = {"doc":{"name": "Sheldon Sid2", "myid": 18})
```

Notice the **doc** in front.  If you do not add the doc on an update and try to run the command

```
resp = es.update(index="myindex",
                     doc_type="default",
                     id=18,
                     body=edit_author1)
```

You will receive the error

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: 
TransportError(400, 'action_request_validation_exception', 
                'Validation Failed: 1: script or doc is missing;')
```

Comment: Elasticsearch wants `body` to be embedded by `doc`

Answer (score 1):

The `index` query is using a rather unnecessary field `doc`, while the `update` query is working as expected it updated the `_source` , not the `doc` inside it.

For the error, the `body` used isn't valid. Use

```
resp = es.update(index="radsearch", doc_type="default", id=18, 
 body={"doc": edit_author1})
```

Refer: [example-usage](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/#example-usage)

Comment: I've been over that 10 times and it is not working as expected.  You did not look at the problem or the question by your answer.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the query to use, do let me know if it helps

Comment: Just updated the question.  The answer you gave does not work and gives a 'Validation Failed: 1: script or doc is missing;')

Comment: First line of my answer says, you're using unnecessary field `doc` while indexing(which is initial insert) and about update query i've missed `doc`, as you're already using that in 2nd query. I've edited `update` query